# GCM Server/Sender Setup for Device-to-Device Communication in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I've been reading through the GCM developer page and none of it seems too complicated.  However, from an overview standpoint, I'm confused on exactly what I want.  I have an application on one device that will send some information to another Android device, which then does something with that information.  It's just a pair of doubles.

I've never had any experience doing much web communication aside from simple website/router stuff, so I realize this is a very inexperienced question-- but when I set up GCM on my two devices, what device is acting as the "server" and which as the "client"?  Are both clients and Google is the server?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you Want to Make Two side communication. you can Do One think that Save your RegistrationID of phone on to the Server. what ever the Data you want to communicate you should save it First to server. and whenever the Notification sent by the Server it will give information to perticular Client with using Registration ID.

Answer (score 0):

Both android devices are considered clients. The clients will communicate with a backend server which can be implemented in a variety of ways. The sample that Google provides uses a standard web app written for the Java App Engine. You can find the example here:

[Setting Up the Server](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html)

You can also write the server using ASP.NET, PHP, etc. What I typically will have on the backend is also a SQL database to manage the devices that are registered with my application. Each device (client) is given a unique ID from Google which the server will use to communicate. The server uses this ID because the messages it will send is not directly to the client but to GCM service. So in essence the Google GCM is a server to your backend server which is a client to GCM.

Hopefully this answers your questions regarding client/server communication. Please look at Googles demo for detailed implementation. Good luck!